# Scaling of Gaussian Equation

Tags: ios, algorithm, image-processing, gaussian

I'm using Gaussian equation for a particular photo effect in an iOS application.

I use:

```
   double sigmaX = ...; //some value here

   for(int i=0;i<height;i++) 
    {
       double F = 0;
       double step = -(pos)*width/20;

    /*height,width,pos - all predefined, no problem there*/

     for(int j=0;j<4*width;j+=4)
     {

      F = (double) ((1/1)*exp(-sigmaX*(pow((step++)/1, 2.0)))) ;
      //do some operation here...

      }
    }
```

and the value of F is used to determine a particular intensity which is used up elsewhere.

So far so good.... F is the typical bell curve as expected.

But, the question is, I want to scale the standard deviation of this curve as per user input.

For example, in the following image, I'd like to shift the curve from the green to the red line (blue maybe an intermediate), hopefully in linear steps:

[image: Variance of SD of Gaussian Curve]

Now, given the standard notation of:

[image: gaussian curve equation]

and comparing it with the way I implemented it in my code, I got the idea to vary 1/sqrt(sigmaX) to alter the scale/SD. I tried incrementing 1/sqrt(sigmaX) in linear steps (to get linear increment) or by x^n to get power of n increment in SD, but none of that worked.

I am a bit stuck with the concept.

Can you please let me know how to scale the Standard Deviation by a predefined ratio, i.e I may want it 1.34 or 3.78 times the oirginal SD and it will scale up the the +3sigma to -3sigma span accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation here:

```
F = (double) ((1/1)*exp(-sigmaX*(pow((step++)/1, 2.0)))) ;
```

Is not reflecting the Gaussian formula you showed. It should be something like this:

```
double dSigma = 1.0;
static const double dRootTwoPi = sqrt(2.0 * M_PI);

F = (1.0 / (dSigma * dRootTwoPi)) * exp(-0.5 * pow(step++ / dSigma, 2.0));
```

Then you can vary `dSigma` from 1.0 to 3.0 (or whatever) to get the effect you want.

Comment: I did not mean to follow the standard format exactly in my code.... that is why I changed the 1.0 / (dSigma * dRootTwoPi) part to 1/1 (just a constant). and so I'm trying to vary 1/sqrt(sigmaX) instead of sigmaX alone. What you mentioned here is the standard accepted implementation of Gaussian equation... but the problem is exp(-sigmaX*(pow((step++)/1, 2.0))) worked well for my case here :) ,so I got lazy and implemented that in quite a few places, everything was fine, except the 'scaling up and down' bit is going wrong. can we fix this equation as it is? theoretically, it can't be impossible!

Comment: It's not easy because, assuming sigma is 1.0, you should have changed to something like (1/2.5) rather than (1/1) as the divisor in the `pow` is also sigma (1.0) - so your equation use two different sigmas already. You can't fix that by changing the scalar on the `exp` though - sure you'll get a Gaussian-like curve, but it won't be a Gaussian. I think this is the root of your original problem.

Comment: Yes Roger, you're right. What I'm doing is not gaussian, its a gaussian look-alike. working on changing the code right now. will post the results once I get it to work. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Roger Rowland, for the help... I finally got this to work:

Changed the gaussian function to:

```
   sigmaX*=scaling;
   F = (double) ((scaling / (sigmaX))*exp(-0.0005*(powf((step++/sigmaX), 2.0)))) ;
```

Indeed, what I had done before wasn't exactly Gaussian. This works fine and scales fine, based on the *scaling* parameter.

Thanks again.